# Splitting program into two classes

Tags: c#

I am in the process of creating a basic data storage program in C#. I am fairly new, please go easy on me. I want to split this into two classes so somebody else would be able to run it from their own main method. My problem is, that I have no idea where to start with this. I tried adding another .cs file for the methods, but the references to arrays and such create errors in the program. Here is what I have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Basic_Item_Entry
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This program is designed to take input and hold          data for 10 items");
            //make array for item #'s and add 10 values
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 10 item numbers");
            int[] itemNums = new int[10];
            for(int i = 0; i <itemNums.Length; i++)
            {

                itemNums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            //make array for item descriptions 
            string[] itemDesc = new string[10];
            for(int i = 0; i < itemNums.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the description for item number: " +     itemNums[i]);
                itemDesc[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            //add contents of arrays to a file @"C:\temp\DataEntry.txt"
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                @"C:\temp\DataEntry.txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine("Item Data:");
                for (int i = 0; i < itemNums.Length; i++)
                {
                    file.WriteLine("Item number " + itemNums[i] + " Description: " + itemDesc[i]);

                }
                file.Close();
            }
            //finish and maybe print contents from file
            Console.WriteLine("Data has been recorded to a file. Would you like                       to view the the contents? y/n");
            //print array data from previously written to file                 @"C:\temp\DataEntry.txt"
            try
            {
                if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("y"))
                {
                    using (StreamReader stringRead = new     StreamReader(@"C:\temp\DataEntry.txt"))
                    {
                        String DataEntryTXT = stringRead.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(DataEntryTXT);

                    }
                }
                //dont print anything, just exit (Still creates the file)
                else
                {
                    System.Environment.Exit(1);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me see what I can do.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Nothing will be gained if I just cleaned up your code for you. Instead, try this. Wherever you feel like "Here I do blah" Meaning it is a new idea. Break that into a method. and pass in the vars you're using and return the result value to be used. *Put static in front of the method names because you haven't created an instance of this class.

Comment: Thank you Dan, I definitely don't just want the answer. I just don't know where to start, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Item Object - Stores an instance of an item (Number, Description)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicDataStorageApp
{
    public class Item
    {
        private int _number;

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set { _number = value; }
        }

        private string _description;

        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; }
        }

        public Item(int number, string description)
            : this()
        {
            _number = number;
            _description = description;
        }

        public Item()
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Item number {0} Description {1}", _number, _description);
        }
    }
}
```

Model Object - Stores a collection of Items and includes methods to read and write to a file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicDataStorageApp
{
    public class Model
    {
        private Item[] _items;

        public Item[] Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; }
        }

        public bool WriteItems(string filename, bool append)
        {
            if (_items != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
                {
                    string str = _items[i].ToString();
                    FileHelper.WriteLine(str, filename, append);
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> ReadItems(string filename)
        {
            return FileHelper.ReadLines(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

FileHelper - Provides read and write IO static methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicDataStorageApp
{
    public static class FileHelper
    {
        public static bool WriteLines(IEnumerable<string> lines, string filename, bool append)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, append))
                {
                    foreach (var line in lines)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static bool WriteLine(string line, string filename, bool append)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename, append))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                var lines = new List<string>();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    string line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }

                return lines;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program - Includes the described logic to get user input, write it to a file and read it back to the user

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicDataStorageApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static Model _model;
        const int _totalInput = 10;
        const string _filename = @"C:\temp\DataEntry.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _model = new Model();
            _model.Items = new Item[_totalInput];

            Console.WriteLine("This program is designed to take input and hold data for 10 items");

            int i = 0;
            while (i < _totalInput)
            {
                int number = -1;

                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter number: ");
                string numberValue = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Int32.TryParse(numberValue, out number))
                {
                    _model.Items[i] = new Item(number, null);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter description: ");
                    string descriptionValue = Console.ReadLine();

                    _model.Items[i].Description = descriptionValue;

                    i++;
                }
            }

            _model.WriteItems(_filename, true);

            var itemStrings = _model.ReadItems(_filename);
            foreach (var s in itemStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```